# uploading excel/CSV file data into database

Tags: php, excel, upload

I have to write a code were i need to import the email ids of people with their names which will be on a excel sheet into the database, but the issue which am facing is, it is inserting blank data into the database,please help, am new to this concept,pardon me if i went wrong somewhere.

**DB Structure**[image]

**import.php**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">File Upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="200" required="">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Import" value="Import">Upload</button>
</form>
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","***","***","***");
    echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
                  $count = 0;
                  while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                             {
                              $count++;
                        if($count>1){
                               $query = "INSERT INTO import_email (via, vault_no, name, email, created_at) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['via']."', '".$_SESSION['vault_no']."', '$name[0]', '$email[1]', NOW())";
                                           mysqli_query($con, $query);
                        }
                    }
                 fclose($file);
            echo 'CSV File has been successfully Imported';
        //header('Location: profile_1.php');
    }else{
        echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File';
    }
}
?>
```

**EXCEL Structure(.csv format)**
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: In your while loop check $emapData with print_r(), if it is having some value or not?

Comment: Okay sir,,ill check it out

Comment: Sir its giving out some weird and  unknown data format like "��l洱�T��^z�"BRV��YH�P�G�W�l�#^m19���J���`��R?���*[�%�a�'3g [2] => ���"

Comment: That's why the data is not inserting properly. Resolve this issue first.

Comment: Sorry..but can you please guide me to resolve this issue i mean what might be the problem, above i have provided complete code, is it having the issue..?

Comment: That's a csv file not excel correct?

Comment: Yes..sir its a csv file is it a the problem..??

Comment: Try this:
http://phppot.com/php/php-csv-file-read/